# Will TLS 1.2 incur more CPU cost than 1.0 ?

Tags: ssl, tls1.2

Will moving a service from TLS 1.0 to 1.2 incur additional CPU load?  The service terminates thousands of incoming TLS connections per minute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The TLS 1.2 protocol by itself will not cause more load then TLS 1.0. The CPU load depends more on the certificate used (size of key) and the ciphers. As for the certificates there is no difference to TLS 1.0. But TLS 1.2 offers some more ciphers and some of these (like [ChaCha20-Poly1305](https://blog.cloudflare.com/do-the-chacha-better-mobile-performance-with-cryptography/)) might even cause less CPU load than ciphers available with TLS 1.0 or might offer better security for the same CPU load.

Comment: That was what I was assuming based on what I've read - it's really the key exchange and actual encryption that cause CPU load.  Thanks